# Move insertion with unordered_map having multiple values

Tags: c++, c++11, range, unordered-map

I tried the below code for move and initializer list insertions. The later works but not the move insertion. Can someone help me with the right solution here ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;


int main ()
{
  std::unordered_map<std::string,std::pair<double, double>>
              myrecipe;

  myrecipe.insert (std::make_pair<std::string,std::make_pair<double,double>>("eggs",(1.0,6.0)));
  myrecipe.insert ( {{"sugar",{0.8, 1.0}},{"salt",{0.1, 2.0}}} );   

  std::cout << "myrecipe contains:" << std::endl;
  for (auto& x: myrecipe)
    std::cout << x.first << ": " << x.second.first << ":" << x.second.second << std::endl;

  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "works"? What do you expect and what is the result you get?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Off-topic: When you are using `using namespace std;` you don't need to use `std::` before your functions. But it's a good practice to avoid `using namespace std;`:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line has a few problems:

`myrecipe.insert (std::make_pair<std::string,std::make_pair<double,double>>("eggs",(1.0,6.0)));`

The type you want to insert is a `std::pair<std::string, std::pair<double, double>>`, but that is not what you are making here. This is how to make it work with `make_pair`:

`myrecipe.insert(std::make_pair<std::string, std::pair<double, double>>("eggs", std::make_pair<double, double>(1.0, 6.0)));`

Or in a more readable format, that relies on template argument type deduction:

`myrecipe.insert(std::make_pair("butter", std::make_pair(2.0, 3.0)));`

[Godbolt link, so you can see it work.](https://godbolt.org/z/4GYWce)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the pair on the doubles, not the complete insert:

```
myrecipe.insert(("eggs",std::make_pair<double,double>(1.0,6.0)));
```

To clarify:
`<std::string,std::pair<double, double>>` is not a `std::pair`, it is a key-value pair (sic!).
Your `std::pair<double, double>` instead is a "real" `std::pair` (or someone could say a 2-tuple) which can be used in C++ as a `std::pair`. Therefore you need the `std::make_pair_call`

Comment: main.cpp:14:66: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::unordered_map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::pair<double, double> >::insert(std::pair<double, double>)’
   myrecipe.insert(("eggs",std::make_pair<double,double>(1.0,6.0)));

Answer (score 0):

If you change that line to `myrecipe.insert ({"eggs",{1.0,6.0}});` it should work as intended

Also, `std::make_pair<double,double>` should not appear as a template parameter since it is not a type but a function that returns an object.

Comment: an initializer_list is created with the first entry being treated as a 'key' and the rest as the 'value' and they are 'moved' into the map